# Is it possible to create loop device in openvz?

Tags: linux, openvz

I have openvz vps and as I can see there's no disk device. But I really need to have a disk device there to check one thing.

The question is, can I create fake disk device that would be able to work with commands such as df or sfdisk?

Comment: (I believe the answer is "no".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a user of OpenVZ, but on a standard Linux system I would create a big file and then just setup a [loopback device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device).

```
# create 50mb file to act as my block device
dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/loopfs bs=1M count=50
# setup loopback device
losetup /dev/loop0 /srv/loopfs
# verify that I have a loopback device.
fdisk -l /dev/loop0

Disk /dev/loop0: 52 MB, 52428800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6 cylinders, total 102400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

# and detach the device because I am done.
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

See:

- man [losetup](http://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup)

Comment: Very good, but very irrelevant.

Comment: Why?  Are loopback devices blocked on openvz, or what?

Comment: It's OpenVZ specific question, everybody does know how to use `dd` and `losetup` in general. I guess it's even already answered in SF.

Comment: I highly doubt 'everyone' knows how to use losetup.  It is not a common task.  I just did a search on OpenVZ, and some of the hits suggest that loopback devices may be used if OpenVZ is configured a certain way.

Comment: Well, it's trivial anyways, even if you're dull beggar to perceive "everybody" directly. Yeah, in OpenVZ you can set-up a VE to access block devices outside, but it's *outside* and you need access to VE0 aka HN to do that.

Comment: @poige, I don't work with disks a lot in linux, so I didn't know about loop devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, openvz doesn't allow working with loop devices. At least you can't do it without technical support from VPS provider.

Comment: I'm being told by OpenVZ representative that block loopback device is intentionaly prohibited since it can crash the kernel. Fuse is being adviced for use instead.

Comment: @poige, thanks! Could you add this info as answer so I could mark it?

Comment: No, til it's on-hold, there's no way to provide answers to the question.